# Code translations from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm making a conversion from 2 clases that `extends ListActivity` to `extend ListFragment` due to code proposals.

As I know, the Fragment is related to the Activity, so at first using `getActivity()...` should do the work to adapt most methods. Other times, I've defined `Activity activity_context;` and I use this.

Anyway, I have some functions that I'm not able to adapt, and I would need some help.

**The first is:** `RecentCallsListActivity extends Fragment`

```
public class RecentCallsListActivity extends ListFragment
...

private static final class QueryHandler extends AsyncQueryHandler {
    private final WeakReference<RecentCallsListActivity> mActivity;
    ...

public QueryHandler(Context context) {
        super(context.getContentResolver());
        mActivity = new WeakReference<RecentCallsListActivity>(
                (RecentCallsListActivity) context); //GETTING THE ERROR HERE
    }
```

**ERROR**: *Cannot cast from context to RecenCallsListActivity*

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle state) {
    super.onActivityCreated(state);

    mQueryHandler = new QueryHandler(activity_context);
```

**The second is:** `CallDetailActivity extends Fragment`

```
public class CallDetailActivity extends ListFragment
...

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CALL: {
            // Make sure phone isn't already busy before starting direct call
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)
                    getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            if (tm.getCallState() == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,
                        Uri.fromParts("tel", mNumber, null));
                startActivity(callIntent);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);  //GETTING IT HERE
}
```

**ERROR**: *The method onkeyDown(int, keyevent) is undefined for the type ListFragment*

Comment: Where are you calling `QueryHandler` and what is the parameter? ... as looking in your code, that should be a class that is or extends `RecentCallsActivity`. For the second error you need to delegate the call from Activity to your fragment

Comment: @gunar For the first: `QueryHandler` is in `RecentCallsActivity` class, and I call it on the `onActivityCreated` this way `mQueryHandler = new QueryHandler(activity_context);` For the second: I don't understand what you mean, could you make a simple example of how to do it? I'll accept your answer if works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `QueryHandler` 
   At runtime you're providing a class that is not a `RecentCallsListActivity` or extend from it. The way of handling this is to define an interface that exposes an API that should be implemented by parent activity. If you have multiple activities that need to implement this interface and have the same implementation, you can make a super Activity that implements your interface and each of your activity will extend from this super class. But if you have a single class don't need to do this.
2. `onKeyDown` handling - as you can [see from API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html), the fragment doesn't expose any `onKeyDown`. I have some ideas why this was not implemented, but you can delegate this action from activity to fragment, so that if the fragment is not present and it doesn't wish to `consume` the event, then you can call activity's `super.onKeyDown`.

Maybe some code will provide some light and will be helpful. 
*Sample fragment class:*

```
public class QueryFragment extends Fragment {
    public static interface RecentCallsLister {
        public void someAction();
    }

    private RecentCallsLister recentCallsListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (activity instanceof RecentCallsLister) {
            this.recentCallsListener = (RecentCallsLister) activity;
        } else {
            throw new ClassCastException("Parent class does not implement RecentCallsLister");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        this.recentCallsListener = null;
        super.onDetach();
    }

    public boolean manageOnKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CALL) {
            // your specific code
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

*Sample parent activity class:*

```
public class QueryParentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements RecentCallsLister {
    private static final String QUERY_FRAGMENT_TAG = "QUERY_FRAGMENT_TAG";

    protected void addQueryFragment() {
        QueryFragment fragment = new QueryFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.where_do_want_to_have_me, fragment, QUERY_FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void someAction() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (queryFragmentConsumedKeyDown(keyCode, event)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private boolean queryFragmentConsumedKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(QUERY_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        if (fragment != null) {
            return ((QueryFragment) fragment).manageOnKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT** for your first issue: 
replace the `QueryHandler` constructor from:

```
public QueryHandler(Context context) {
    super(context.getContentResolver());
    mActivity = new WeakReference<RecentCallsListActivity>((RecentCallsListActivity) context);
    }
```

to:

```
public QueryHandler(Context context, RecentCallsListActivity fragmentInstance) {
    super(context.getContentResolver());
    mActivity = new WeakReference<RecentCallsListActivity>(fragmentInstance);
}
```

Instantiate it as: `mQueryHandler = new QueryHandler(activity_context, this);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @gunar, I think that I've made a mistake defining the QueryHandler's class, it is on the RecentCallsListActivity class. I've updated the post to be more clearly wich method belongs to each class. I haven't enough knowledge to understend all your answer, I think is more elaborated than what I need, and I apreciate a lot your help, but it would be more helpful for me if you could edit your answer to something easier

Comment: `RecentCallsListActivity` is a fragment class in the end? :)

Comment: RecentCallsListActivity.java is a fragment, CallDetailActivity.java is also fragment, sorry, I've mistaked it when telling to you before

Comment: I've updated again the post. I've added above the QueryHandler method, the class to wich it belongs, this class is inside RecentCallsListActivity.java

Comment: change `mQueryHandler = new QueryHandler(activity_context);` to: `mQueryHandler = new QueryHandler(this);`

Comment: Error: `The constructor RecentCallsListActivity.QueryHandler(RecentCallsListActivity) is undefined`. Fix available: `Change constructor QueryHandler(context) to QueryHandler(RecentCallsListActivity)`

Comment: Yeah, wasn't paying too much attentions ... The constructor receives a Context and you're forcing a class cast to a Fragment and that will always fail.

Comment: Ok, works! for the second issue, I've made: `return super.getActivity().onKeyDown(keyCode, event);` At a first look it doesn't throw any error, but please confirm me that is correct

Comment: Actually, it would be best to handle the key down in the Activity so if you decide later to remove the fragment you won't have to touch the key down handling. Also, maybe you decide later to change the keydown functionality so it will do both fragment and activity keydown. Do you have any issues with what I've wrote in the answer for this key down handling?

Comment: Well, I dont have Activities on my app, I've got the main FragmentActivity and other classes are Fragments. This onKeyDown functionality refers to the code that I adapted from the stock RecentCalls code to create a custom interfaze for the Call log view. So truly, I'm not very sure about what it does. For the moment I just want to keep it where it is, make it work, and in a future when I learn a bit more about this functionality and if I need to implement it, then I would consider to change it to other place.

Comment: Without activities how do you run your fragments? :P

Comment: Either you completely handle `onKeyDown` in your activity, either you delegate the `onKeyDown` to fragment as described above. The `Fragment` class has no means of detecting key downs.

Comment: Well, I have the Main FragmentActivity to run them!! xD So, you recomnd me to put the onKeyDown on the FragmentActivity? But how to do this? I just a bit lost now with this, so Supossing that I have the 2 framents described on the post, and a FragmentActivity where I implement the onClickListeners to call the fragments, what would be the code to put there, because the functions makes some references that are from the CallDetailActivity class. Im just giving you upvote and accepted answer, for all your help.

Comment: `FragmentActivity` **is-a** `Activity`. And `Activity` class has `onKeyDown` ... `Fragment` doesn't have it so the OS will not call it. That's why you have to delegate this call from `Activity` to `Fragment` class. Makes sense? ... It's basically what I've wrote.